# Can zmq::message_t's be reused after being sent?

Tags: segmentation-fault, ipc, zeromq

I'm using ZeroMQ to implement a toy communications protocol; and this is my first time using this framework/library.

Now, in my protocol, multiple consecutive messages get sent by a certain party, all of which have the same size. So - I thought, I'd avoid reallocating them, and just try to refill the message data buffer with different content, e.g.:

```
zmq::message_t msg { fixed_common_size };
while (some_condition()) {
    my_filling_routine(msg.data(), fixed_common_size);
    the_socket.send(msg);
}
```

but on the second iteration of this loop, I get a segmentation fault; `msg.data()` is not `nullptr` though. It occurred to me, that maybe ZeroMQ cannibalizes the memory somehow, and thus I need to write something like:

```
zmq::message_t msg { fixed_common_size };
char buffer[fixed_common_size];
while (some_condition()) {
    my_filling_routine(buffer, fixed_common_size);
    msg.rebuild(buffer, fixed_common_size);
    the_socket.send(msg);
}
```

But I'm sure this causes de-allocation and re-allocation.

So, is it really the case that a `rebuild()` is necessary, or could it just be some bug in my code?

Note: I'm using Unix sockets, in case the answer depends on that somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No, you can't reuse a **`zmq::message_t`**'s after it was sent.

First, welcome to ZeroMQ, a cool place to be in for [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) practitioners.

The ZeroMQ API warns about these issues quite explicitly. A successful call to **`zmq_msg_send()`**, referencing a message-payload, does not mean that the message itself has been actually sent.

It's best you try to imagine that the call **just "moves" the responsiblity** from your application code to the ZeroMQ engine (inside the factory with a pool-of-IOthreads instantiated inside the `Context()`-instance ... ).

> The **`zmq_msg_t`** structure passed to **`zmq_msg_send()`** is *nullified* during the call.

and next better **never** touch it anytime later as reported above :o)

The maximum "ecological"-bypass of allocator is to re-use the **whole**-message, as :

> If you want to send **the same** message to multiple sockets you have to copy it using ( e.g. using **`zmq_msg_copy()`** ).

---

#### A bonus warning on copying ...

plus one more raised point: may copy, but dare to try to modify it after this ...

> Avoid modifying message content after a message has been copied with **`zmq_msg_copy()`**, doing so can result in undefined behaviour. If what you need is an actual hard copy, allocate a new message using **`zmq_msg_init_size()`** and copy the message content using `memcpy()`.
>   
>   Never access `zmq_msg_t` members directly, instead always use the `zmq_msg`-family of functions.

Comment: Ok, but that means that you basically need heap allocation with every message (or you pre-allocate and advance your pointers). Right?

Comment: About your final comment: 1. Is using `zmq::message_t` objects always safe? or can it be as dangerous as accessing `zmq_msg_t` members directly? 2. Should I avoid memcpy()'ing to `my_msg.data()` ?

Comment: Best consider all messages as fragile bodies, not re-usables or DIY-s. There are rules, where zero-copy may be beneficial to one's code, but in general, be carefull what is documented as being safe and consider all the rest as a not recommended practice. Low level tricks may have been tolerated in older versions, so be rather cautious. The best next step seems to be to review the API version 4.2, and check what API was used in re-wrapping the native ZeroMQ version and its preferred, resp. deprecated strategies.