# Streaming images with ZMQ, message_t allocation takes too much time

Tags: c++, memory-management, zeromq

I've been trying to find out how to stream images with zeromq (i'm using the cppzmq wrapper, but raw API answers are fine). Naively, I set up

```
zmq::context_t ctx(4);
zmq::socket_t pub_image_socket(ctx, zmq::socket_type::pub);
pub_image_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:8001");

...

while(true){
     //render to image...
     zmq::message_t image_message(image_size.x*image_size.y*element_size);
     copy_image_to(image, image_message);
     pub_image_socket.send(image_message, zmq::send_flags::none);
}
```

I thought that maybe some other part of the zmq chain was taking a bunch of time, so I did the following (in a debug build):

```
//zmq::context_t ctx(4);
//zmq::socket_t pub_image_socket(ctx, zmq::socket_type::pub);
//pub_image_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:8001");

...

while(true){
     //render to image...
     zmq::message_t image_message(image_size.x*image_size.y*element_size);
     //commented out so only message creation left
     //copy_image_to(image, image_message);
     //pub_image_socket.send(image_message, zmq::send_flags::none);
}
```

there was no movement in the runtime (and the visual studio profiler could not actually tell me what the slow-down was).

So then I decided to do this:

```
zmq::context_t ctx(4);
zmq::socket_t pub_image_socket(ctx, zmq::socket_type::pub);
pub_image_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:8001");

...

while(true){
     //render to image...
     //zmq::message_t image_message(image_size.x*image_size.y*element_size);
     //commented out so only message creation left
     //copy_image_to(image, image_message);
     //pub_image_socket.send(image_message, zmq::send_flags::none);
}
```

Commenting out the `image_message` more than doubled my runtime... I'm not sure what I can do to stop this though, theoretically I could stop this by re-using the allocated memory in a message_t but [zmq prohibits this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50090863/).  Allocating megabytes per frame just takes too much time.

I'm starting to think data streaming is impossible for ZeroMQ due to this limitation, and I should just use asio and tcp/udp sockets instead. Is there a way to avoid this massive reallocation cost in ZMQ?

Comment: Streams and message queues is not exactly the perfect match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zmq_msg_init_data`

http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-msg-init-data

You can provide the memory pointer/size of your already allocated memory and zeromq will take ownership (skipping the extra allocation).  Once its been processed and is no longer needed it will call the associated free function where your own code can clean up.

I have used this approach in the past with a memory pool/ circular buffer and it worked well.

Comment: Interesting, I've moved on to using TCP directly, but I already have to use a circular buffer, I had seen this before, but my  mind was stuck thinking about "I have to use the messag_t before hand".  With this, message_t is still created in the loop, but doesn't allocate a giant buffer. I guess I'd use the destructor function to let my code know one of the buffers was available.